# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while making a list

Tags: c, list, file, segmentation-fault

I want to create a list which reads information about some players (name and some integer values) from a data file.

I want to create a list which contains a players name and calculates the overall score.

When I try to run the code below, I get segmentation fault. The program exits just after this: strcpy(head->name,current->name) and I don't know why. There are probably different ways to write this code, but I would like to understand what is happening here. Here is the part of the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct playerList{
    char name[31];
    double points;
    playerList *next;
} players;

int main()
{
    FILE *o;
    int p1,p2,p3; 
    players *head=(players*)malloc(sizeof(players)), 
            *current=(players*)malloc(sizeof(players)),
            *previous;
    head=NULL; 
    if((o=fopen("players.txt","r"))==NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file.");
        exit(1);
    }
    while((fgets(current->name,30,o)!=NULL)) {
        fscanf(o,"%*d %*d %d %d %d",&p1,&p2,&p3);
        if(!head) {
            strcpy(head->name,current->name);
            head->points=p1+p2*0.5+p3*0.2;
            previous=head;
        }
        else {
            current->points=p1+p2*0.5+p3*0.2;
            previous->next=current;
            previous=current;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without looking, a crash on strcpy() is almost always a bad pointer passed into it.  FYI, casting malloc is not a good idea.  I'll await the standard link from others on why.

Comment: In the case where if (!head) is true, that means head is NULL, and if you dereference a NULL pointer like you do in the first statement inside the if clause, you will crash

Comment: malloc of head and then immediately setting to null is a memory leak.

Comment: also, your `fscanf` call is bad. You have five format specifiers, but only 3 variables.

Comment: Honestly, this code isn't at all going to do well.  You need to step through it with a debugger and see why.  Typically for a linked list, you create a new "node", fill it in with data, then link the head pointer to it and make it the new head.  You are copying data in strange places that I really don't want to follow.  Also, always compile with warnings enabled.  -Wall will give a lots of hints.

Answer (score 0):

At the begging you set head = NULL and in while loop you have if statement if(!head) , witch is true because your head is NULL (false) and the logic negative will make this statement true .
In that if statement body you are trying to copy a value from NULL and that why you are facing with segmentation fault .

Comment: Tnx for your answer. However, I'm copying a value to null, (head->name is the destination), and I think that is allowed even if head is NULL?